# android - Как отправлять запрос на сервер в цикле?

Tags: android, retrofit, request

Есть база с данными, поочередно беру данные и передаю в запрос. Нужно выполнить перебор всех данных, то есть отправлять условно 7 запросов подряд, получая ответ с сервера проверять что пришло, если ошибка - то продолжаем, если нормальный ответ - то закончить отправку запросов. Пробовал через цикл `while`, ничего не вышло. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
 public  void methodWhile(){
    while (true){
        macc = arrayMac[d];
        mRquest(macc);
        Log.d("qwe", "Ответ с сервера = " + code);
        if (code == 1 || code == 2){
            Log.d("qwe","true");
            schag++;
            d++;
            Log.d("qwe", "Кол-во шагов " + schag);
        //   break;
        }
        else {

            Log.d("qwe","false"+ "" + code);
            break;
        }
    }
}


public  void  mRquest(String bmac){

         Map<String, String> query = new HashMap<String, String>();
            query.put("bmac",bmac);
            query.put("cmac", mydeviceAddress);
            query.put("rsi", "-50");
            //Response response = service.search(parameters);
            Log.d("qwe", "Map Created");
            apiService.search(query);
            Call<Example> call = apiService.search(query);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
                @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Example mExample = response.body();
                        Log.d("qwe", "Запрос выполнился успешно");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("qwe", "Сервер вернул ошибку");
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("qwe", "Произошла ошибка при выполненни запроса");
                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: а какая именно ошибка была?

Comment: что в цикле указывал? как делаешь запросы в бд?

Comment: Я пользовался retrofit, ошибка была в логике , я просто не знаю как передавать ответ обратно в цикл , чтобы понять , остановить цикл или нет .

Comment: Пока не подключал базу , данные беру с массива строк.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать RealTime базу данных от самого гугла, [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) называется. Данные получаете там через асинхронный запрос(причем все сразу в snapshot'e, а дальше работаете с ними как вам удобно - читаете, сортируете, обновляете), у вас сразу отпадает ждать ответа от базы. П.С. вы понимаете, что в случае постоянной посылки запросов к БД можете получить [ANR](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)?